# Faster alternatives to "find" and "locate"?

Tags: linux, unix, find, locate

I will like to use "find" and locate" to search for source files in my project, but they take a long time to run. Are there faster alternatives to these programs I don't know about, or ways to speed up the performance of these programs?

Comment: `locate` should already be plenty fast, considering that it uses a pre-built index (the primary caveat being that it needs to be kept up to date), while `find` has to read the directory listings.

Comment: Which locate are you using?  mlocate is faster than slocate by a long way (note that whichever package you have installed, the command is still locate, so check your package manager)

Comment: @benhsu, when I run `find /usr/src -name fprintf.c` on my OpenBSD desktop machine, it returns the locations of those source files in less than 10 seconds. `locate fprintf.c | grep '^/usr/src.*/fprintf.c$'` comes back in under a second. What is your definition of "long time to run" and how do you use `find` and `locate`?

Comment: @Paul, I am using mlocate.

Comment: @KAK, I would like to use the output of find/locate to open a file in emacs. the use case I have in mind is, I wish to edit the file, I type  the file name (or some regexp matching the file name) into emacs, and emacs will use find/locate to bring up a list of files matching it, so I will like response time fast enough to be interactive (under 1 second). 

I have about 3 million files in $HOME, one thing I can do is make my find command prune out some of the files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Searching for source files in a project

**Use a simpler command**

Generally, source for a project is likely to be in one place, perhaps in a few subdirectories nested no more than two or three deep, so you can use a (possibly) faster command such as

```
(cd /path/to/project; ls *.c */*.c */*/*.c)
```

**Make use of project metadata**

In a C project you'd typically have a Makefile. In other projects you may have something similar. These can be a fast way to extract a list of files (and their locations) write a script that makes use of this information to locate files. I have a "sources" script so that I can write commands like `grep variable $(sources programname)`.

### Speeding up find

Search fewer places, instead of `find / …` use `find /path/to/project …` where possible. Simplify the selection criteria as much as possible. Use pipelines to defer some selection criteria if that is more efficient.

Also, you can limit the depth of search. For me, this improves the speed of 'find' a lot. You can use -maxdepth switch. For example '-maxdepth 5'

### Speeding up locate

Ensure it is indexing the locations you are interested in. Read the man page and make use of whatever options are appropriate to your task.

```
   -U <dir>
          Create slocate database starting at path <dir>.

   -d <path>
          --database=<path> Specifies the path of databases to search  in.


   -l <level>
          Security  level.   0  turns  security checks off. This will make
          searchs faster.   1  turns  security  checks  on.  This  is  the
          default.
```

### Remove the need for searching

Maybe you are searching because you have forgotten where something is or were not told. In the former case, write notes (documentation), in the latter, ask? Conventions, standards and consistency can help a lot.

Answer (score 13):

I used the "speeding up locate" part of RedGrittyBrick's answer. I created a smaller db:

```
updatedb -o /home/benhsu/ben.db -U /home/benhsu/ -e "uninteresting/directory1 uninteresting/directory2"
```

then pointed `locate` at it: `locate -d /home/benhsu/ben.db`

Answer (score 9):

For a find replacement, check out [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#benchmark). It has a simpler / more intuitive interface than the original find command, and is quite a bit faster.

Comment: Hooray, it's parallelized!

Answer (score 8):

As of early 2021 I evaluated a few tools for similar use cases and integration with [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf):

**tl;dr:** **`plocate`** is a *very* fast alternative to `mlocate` in most cases. (GNU) **`find`** often still seems to be hard to beat for tools which don't require an index.

## `locate`-likes (using indices)

I compared the commonly used `mlocate` and [`plocate`](https://plocate.sesse.net/). In a database of about 61 million files `plocate` answers specific queries (a couple of hundred results) in the order of 0.01 to 0.2 seconds and only becomes much slower (> 100 seconds) for very unspecific queries with millions of results. `mlocate` takes an almost constant 35 to 40 seconds to query the same database in all tested cases. Most of the time **`plocate` is multiple orders of magnitude faster than `mlocate`.**

## `find`-likes (directory traversal)

It's harder to - sorry - locate a good find alternative and the result very much depends on the specific queries. Here are some results for just trying to find all files in a sample directory (~200.000 files) in descending speed order:

- GNU find (`find -type f`): Surprisingly, **`find` is often the fastest tool** (~ 0.01 seconds)
- plocate (`plocate --regexp "^$PWD"`) (< 0.1 seconds)
- mlocate (`mlocate --regexp "^$PWD"`): Interestingly faster than the non-regexp queries (~ 5 seconds)
- ripgrep (`rg --files --no-ignore --hidden`): A good bit faster, but still very slow (~0.5 seconds)
- fd (`fdfind --type f` on Debian): Not as fast as expected (~0.7 seconds)
- `zsh` globs (`**/*` and extended versions): Generally very slow, but can be elegant in scripts (~3 seconds)

With directory structures not cached in RAM, `plocate` probably beats `find`, especially on disks with high seek times (HDDs), but does of course require an up-to-date database.

A parallelized `find` might give better results on systems which profit from command queuing and can request data in parallel. Depending on use case, this can be implemented in scripts, too, by running multiple instances of `find` on different subtrees, but performance characteristics depend on a lot of factors there.

## `grep`-likes (looking at content)

There's a whole lot of recursive `grep`-like tools with different features, but most offer very limited features for finding files based on their metadata instead of their contents. Even if they are fast like `ag` (silversurfer), `rg` (ripgrep) or `ugrep`, they are not necessarily fast if just looking at file names.

Comment: what type disk is this?  maybe add bash globs? :)

Comment: @rogerdpack The tests have been mostly done with data on fast NVMe and in RAM. If file system structures are not in the cache, HDDs are much slower, but least so with locate (reading the whole database might just require a few seeks).

Comment: Seems fair to add that the slower mlocate is more secure, only showing files that the user has access to. I don't need the security on my Linux desktop, so I'm switching. Thanks!

Comment: When a directory has nested structure `find` will be very slow comparing to `fd` or `rg` because they run in parallel and `find` does not. On 70k nested dirs (max-depth: 3; size: 6.5G) times in sec are 18.38 (`find`), 4.58 (`rg`), 4.55 (`fd`).

Comment: `plocate` might be faster but doesn't have `--transliterate` option (very [useful for non-English users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908881/search-with-diacritics-accents-characters-with-locate-command))

Comment: I just installed `plocate` and I found it to be 100 to 200 times faster than `mlocate`.  Excellent.

Answer (score 7):

A tactic that I use is to apply the `-maxdepth` option with `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname "*target*"
```

Repeat with increasing depths until you find what you are looking for, or you get tired of looking.  The first few iterations are likely to return instantaneously.

This ensures that you don't waste up-front time looking through the depths of massive sub-trees when what you are looking for is more likely to be near the base of the hierarchy.

---

Here's an example script to automate this process (Ctrl-C when you see what you want):

```
(
TARGET="*target*"
for i in $(seq 1 9) ; do
   echo "=== search depth: $i"
   find -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i -iname "$TARGET"
done
echo "=== search depth: 10+"
find -mindepth 10 -iname $TARGET
)
```

Note that the inherent redundancy involved (each pass will have to traverse the folders processed in previous passes) will largely be optimized away through disk caching.

Why doesn't `find` have this search order as a built-in feature?  Maybe because it would be complicated/impossible to implement if you assumed that the redundant traversal was unacceptable.  The existence of the `-depth` option hints at the possibility, but alas...

Comment: ...thus performing a "breadth-first" search.

Answer (score 5):

### [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)

You might found it useful for searching very fast **the content** of a huge number of source code files. Just type `ag <keyword>`.
Here some of the output of my `apt show silversearcher-ag`:

- **Package**: silversearcher-ag
- **Maintainer**: Hajime Mizuno
- **Homepage**: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher
- **[Description](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher#whats-so-great-about-ag)**: very fast grep-like program, alternative to ack-grep
  The Silver Searcher is grep-like program implemented by C. An attempt to make something better than ack-grep.
  It searches pattern about 3–5x faster than ack-grep. [It ignores file patterns from your .gitignore and .hgignore](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/wiki/Advanced-Usage).

I usually use it with:

> [`-G` `--file-search-regex PATTERN`](https://www.mankier.com/1/ag#Options)
>   Only search files whose names match PATTERN.

```
ag -G "css$" important
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: the [ripgrep's](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) algorythm is allegedly faster than silversearch, and it also honors `.gitignore` files and skips `.git`, `.svn`, `.hg`.. folders.

Comment: @ccpizza So? [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) also honors `.gitignore` and ignores hidden and binary files by default. Also have more contributors, more stars on Github (14700 vs 8300) and is already on repos of mayor distros. Please provide an updated reliable third-party source comparison. Nonetheless, `ripgrep` looks a great piece of software.

Comment: good to know! i'm not affiliated with author(s) of `ripgrep` in any way, it just fit my requirement so I stopped searching for other options.

Comment: The silver searcher respects `.gitignore` too. That said, `rg` is absolutely amazing. First off, it has unicode support. In my experience `rg` consistently at least twice as fast as `ag` (YMMV), I guess it's due to Rust's regex parser, that obviously wasn't ready yet back in the years `ag` was new. `rg` can give deterministic output (but doesn't by default), it can blacklist file types where `ag` can only whitelist, it can ignore files based on size (bye bye logs). I still use `ag` in case I need multiline matching, which `rg` can't do.

Answer (score 4):

Another easy solution is to use newer extended shell globbing.
To enable:

- bash: shopt -s globstar
- ksh:  set -o globstar
- zsh:  already enabled

Then, you can run commands like this in the top-level source directory:

```sh
# grep through all c files
grep printf **/*.c

# grep through all files
grep printf ** 2>/dev/null
```

This has the advantage that it searches recursively through all subdirectories and is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If the file/directory you're looking for is likely to be "shallow" (ie. not that many layers deep), you can speed up your search a lot by using a breadth-first search tool like [bfs](https://github.com/tavianator/bfs).

If you know the target is not in a given directory, you can also exclude directories [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210072/2441655).